# Division on DB2

Tags: sql, db2

Hello I am trying to calculate the MPG of my trucks 
this is what I have

```
SELECT DRIVER_ID, UNIT_ID, 
(SELECT SUM(T2.VOL_PFUEL) FROM FC_POS T2 WHERE T2.UNIT_ID = T1.UNIT_ID) AS CUMULATIVE_FUEL_PURCHASE,
(SELECT ODOMETER FROM ODOHIST O WHERE O.UNIT_ID = T1.UNIT_ID ORDER BY READINGDATE DESC FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY) AS ODOMETER,
((SELECT ODOMETER FROM ODOHIST O WHERE O.UNIT_ID = T1.UNIT_ID ORDER BY READINGDATE DESC FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY)/(SELECT SUM(T2.VOL_PFUEL) FROM FC_POS T2 WHERE T2.UNIT_ID = T1.UNIT_ID)) AS MPG
FROM FC_POS T1 WHERE UNIT_ID = '####'
ORDER BY POS_DATE DESC 
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
WITH UR
```

The results are as follows:

```
driver_id: ######
unit_id: #####
cumulative_fuel_purchase: 9180.56
odometer: 65701.3
MPG: 6779107157
```

so when I divide cumulative_fuel_purchase by odometer I should get 7.1 and not that monster above!

I am using DB2 
Thank YOU!

Comment: You get ###### as driverid? Data types?

Comment: Try casting one of the values to an explicit data type such as `decimal(10, 2)`.

Comment: i AM USING #### TO HIDE THAT INFORMATION

Comment: i TRIED USing the decimal but my number is even bigger...

Comment: (SELECT ROUND(DEC(ODOMETER),2) FROM ODOHIST O WHERE O.UNIT_ID = T1.UNIT_ID ORDER BY READINGDATE DESC FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY)/(SELECT ROUND(DEC(SUM(T2.VOL_PFUEL)),2) FROM FC_POS T2 WHERE T2.UNIT_ID = T1.UNIT_ID) AS MPG

Comment: These two were created by using a sub select

Comment: how bat restructuring your query like `SELECT DRIVER_ID, UNIT_ID, T2.CUMULATIVE_FUEL_PURCHASE, T3.ODOMETER, (T3.ODOMETER/T2.CUMULATIVE_FUEL_PURCHASE) AS MPG
FROM FC_POS T1 , (SELECT UNIT_ID, SUM(VOL_PFUEL) AS CUMULATIVE_FUEL_PURCHASE FROM FC_POS WHERE UNIT_ID = ####  GROUP BY UNIT_ID) AS T2, (SELECT UNIT_ID, ODOMETER FROM ODOHIST WHERE UNIT_ID = #### ORDER BY READINGDATE DESC FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY) AS T3 WHERE T1.UNIT_ID = #### AND T1.UNIT_ID = T2.UNIT_ID AND  T1.UNIT_ID = T3.UNIT_ID ORDER BY POS_DATE DESC  FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY WITH UR`

Comment: @PK20 - It's better to avoid the implicit-join syntax, and instead explicitly state `JOIN`s and their conditions.  For one thing, it makes it more obvious what the connections are.

Comment: You're right, you should be getting something close to 7.1 - more accurately, `7.15656779107`... which should look mighty familiar.  How are you calling this query?  Is it part of something larger?  What happens if you just execute a query with the values themselves (making sure to cast to the proper types)?